# How to reuse same UIView in all viewcontrollers in iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Hi I'm new to iOS Development, I'm developing an iOS Application in that I want to use same footer throughout the app. Now I'm creating different uiviews in every controller but this is not optimal way. How can I create single uiview and reuse it in app. I'm using storyboards.In my footer I have four buttons

Comment: create a uiview class and add your footer to it in code, subclass it and use for all your other views.

Comment: Why don't you use `TabBar`? Simple and better way to use TabBar.

Comment: If we use tabbar, all views will have a button in footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your reusable view as a `XIB` and load it programatically where ever you need it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41198987/1457385) shows how to handle `XIB`s.

This should work fine for your footer.

For more complex reusable views, which make sense to have their own `UIViewConroller`:

- create the viewController in storyboard
- instantiate it like this:

  ```
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
  let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
  ```
- add it as child viewController like this:

  ```
  func add(childViewController controller: UIViewController, embedViewIn containerView: UIView) {
      controller.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
      addChildViewController(controller)
      containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
      // addCustomConstraints
  }
  ```

---

You can later remove the child viewController like this:

```
func remove(childViewController controller: UIViewController) {
    controller.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
    controller.removeFromParentViewController()
}
```

Comment: I missed the obj-c tag. Sorry. Beside the syntax, it works the same way.

Comment: how can i do it with storyboards

Comment: You can not use storyboard for the first approach. But XIB is like storyboard for views without vieeController. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use custom tabBar, Have a look at https://github.com/hartlco/MHCustomTabBarController this link, I have implemented it its easy to understand.